# Is there a way to use regex to search for x amount of characters after a keyword but before it reaches '|'?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

When iterating through a list, an example of a string below would be returned. I'm trying to save the team name as a variable. However, for each string to be examined within the list, the name can be any quantity of characters.

As an aside, when saving the total score as a variable, I achieved this through

```
pointTotal = re.search("Total:" + '.\w+', eachEntry)
```

though this will obviously not work for team names that span over multiple words.

My goal is to perform a regex search on all the characters (could also be numbers) that follow 'Name:' till it reaches the pipe symbol (|). Ultimately I would be able to end up with teamName = "Avacado Helmets"

```
..."|Keypad:6 |Name:Avacado Helmets  |Pressed:E  |Seconds:15.73  |Question Points:0  |Total:5802"
```

I hope that this question was not too convoluted, I've been searching through the regex testers to try and figure it out, but I just think I need a bit of guidance. I'm just finding my feet with regex, and programming for that matter, and I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: is there a pipe after `Total:5802` ?

Comment: @GhostOps there isn't one after Total no

Comment: For capturing the name, you can use [`(?<=Name:)[^|]+`](https://regex101.com/r/crAIwi/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` here with a capture group:

```py
inp = "|Keypad:6 |Name:Avacado Helmets |Pressed:E |Seconds:15.73 |Question Points:0 |Total:5802"
name = re.findall(r'\|Name:(.*?)\s*(?:\||$)', inp)[0]
print(name)  # Avocado Helmets
```

Comment: That's perfect and searches for exactly what I'm after. Thank you! Seems there's a lot I need to learn about regex

Answer (score 0):

As [@Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) said in his comment, you can use positive lookbehind and lookahead to get only the Name value using the Regex [`(?<=Name:).+?(?= *\|)`](https://regex101.com/r/bKDzNp/3), like

```py
import re

string = '|Keypad:6 |Name:Avacado Helmets |Pressed:E |Seconds:15.73 |Question Points:0 |Total:5802'
name = re.search(r'(?<=Name:).+?(?= *\|)', string).group()
print(name) # Avacado Helmets
```

And also, as far as I've understood from the question, you can use this code if you wanted to assign all the values you get from the string into a global variables using this Regex [`([A-Z][^:]+):([^|]+?)(?= *\||$)`](https://regex101.com/r/7IUcWS/2)

```py
lst = re.findall(r'([A-Z][^:]+):([^|]+?)(?= *\||$)', string)
for name, value in lst:
    globals()[name] = value
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: You can simplify your regex to `(?<=Name:).+?(?= *\|)`. As `.+?` is lazy it will not match a string containing a pipe.  I've suggested `(?= *\|)` rather than `(?=\s*\|)` as you want to only match spaces, not, for example, newlines. Similarly, `[^|]+?` will match newlines whereas `.+?` will not.